# HTTPS XMLHttpRequest failing to retrieve correct page

Tags: javascript, authentication, https, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get content of a page, but this page is secured using https. I tried to use XMLHttpRequest with a http site and succeeded, but this page does return the redirect of the page where you have to log on.

Below is my code I tried to use:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = xhr.responseXML.body.innerHTML;
    };
};
xhr.open('POST', 'https://eu.battle.net/wow/en/vault/character/auction/alliance/', true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.send();
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "loaded";
```

I tried setting requestheaders, including cookies and authentication and changing the method to GET and POST but no difference.

Can anyone give me a heads up on this request?

P.S. If this is not possible at all, is there any way to succeed using a different method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make AJAX requests cross-domain, unless it returns a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Cross-site HTTP requests initiated from within scripts have been subject to well-known restrictions, for well-understood security reasons.  For example HTTP Requests made using the XMLHttpRequest object were subject to the same-origin policy.  In particular, this meant that a web application using XMLHttpRequest could only make HTTP requests to the domain it was loaded from, and not to other domains.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

You could bypass this using a PHP Proxy:
http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/10/cross-domain-ajax-a-simple-workaround/