# Read xml from url using js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map that reads a XML file local on my server to parse data on a map. Works great. I would like to use a URL straight to the data instead of using WGET to save it to my server. How can I go about using a URL instead?

Currently this is how I set the file path to the WGET file that I am pulling from the URL I want to use directly.

```
var xml     = 'xml/killer-tornados2014.xml';
```

Which the XML file is then read as so. As stated, works great but would like to pull directly from the XML URL for simplicity.

```
downloadUrl(xml, function(data) {
      var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("fatalities");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var yrnum = markers[i].getAttribute("yrnum");
      var dt = markers[i].getAttribute("dt");
      var tm = markers[i].getAttribute("time");
      var ef = markers[i].getAttribute("ef");
      var st = markers[i].getAttribute("st");
      var loc = markers[i].getAttribute("location");
      var watch = markers[i].getAttribute("watch");
      var dead = markers[i].getAttribute("deaths");
      var h = markers[i].getAttribute("h");
      var m = markers[i].getAttribute("m");
      var o = markers[i].getAttribute("o");
      var v = markers[i].getAttribute("v");
      var p = markers[i].getAttribute("p");
      var unk = markers[i].getAttribute("unk");
```

Comment: You probably need to use a proxy.  XmlHttpRequests are subject to the same domain security restriction.  [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700103/https-xmlhttprequest-failing-to-retrieve-correct-page/18701251#18701251)

Comment: I believe you are correct and I had forgot about that. This is probably the reason I went with the approach I have gone with.